# Richfaces 3.3.3.final jar and jsf 1.2 deployment fails on WAS7

Tags: jsf, richfaces, websphere-7

I want to migrate from richfaces 3.3.1 to 3.3.3.Final jar for rich:scrollabledatatable issues (header disappears after rerender).

I am using jsf 1.2. After successfully building the application through maven,I deployed build of my applicaiton on WAS 7, i am getting error saying Deployment failed:
ADMA5069E : The installation of App failed.

If anyone has done migration to 3.3.3.Final, please suggest if apart from pom.xml version change anything else needs to be done.All other web.xml entries etc are same as when i used 3.3.1 richfaces version.

Comment: Please lookup and share the exception/stacktrace causing the deployment fail in the server log. The answer is in there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I checked the log file SystemErr.log and found java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 238 but got 234 bytes) for richfaces jar. I will try to download jars again , will try installing through maven -install command.Will update further when resolved.

Comment: Jars which i downloaded were in zip format, hence the exception.I downloaded jars from grepcode website and they were appropriate.